# How to improve the way I use Textmate for Ruby on Rails, HTML and Javascript?

Tags: html, javascript, textmate, ruby-on-rails

I use the latest version of textmate for all my Rails development needs and I feel that I'm under-using the possibilities or this software since I only installed the ruby on rails bundle and use little to no snippets / shortcuts.

What do I absolutely HAVE to know / do in order to get the most out of my textmate?

Comment: Because this is related to developing in ruby and JS an creating html, it might be appropriate to ask on StackOverflow or research there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textmate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gotten familiar with the macros for Ruby on Rails?

Check them out on the "Bundles" In the menu bar.